# Creating a hash of lambda's referencing instance methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lambda, hash, binding

I have a class with a hash of lambda's pointing to methods in the class.

```
Thing.new.call
=> undefined local variable or method `do_foo' for Thing:Class
```

I was expecting

```
Thing.new.call
=> foo
=> bar
```

The lambda's seem to be calling `do_foo` and `do_bar` as class methods instead of instance methods. Can I fix this? I don't want to use `send(command)` as the commands can be updated by a user and can be a hacking risk.

Link to a [replit](https://replit.com/@richardmaccaw/SwiftEnviousRar#main.rb)

```
class Thing

   def initialize
     @commands = [:foo, :bar]
   end
 
   SAFE_COMMANDS = {
     foo: -> { do_foo },
     bar: -> { do_bar }
   }  

   def call
     @commands.each { |command| SAFE_COMMANDS[command].call }
   end

   private

   def do_foo 
     puts 'foo'
   end

   def do_bar
     puts 'bar'
   end

end
```

Comment: You could use `foo: instance_method(:do_foo)` and then `SAFE_COMMANDS[command].bind(self).call` but I don't understand what you mean by "the commands can be updated by a user".

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your `SAFE_COMMANDS` array and the lambdas in it are being defined in class context, therefore it is trying to call class methods.

You can pass the instance to the lambdas so that you can call its instance methods.

```
class Thing

  def initialize
    @commands = [:foo, :bar]
  end
 
  SAFE_COMMANDS = {
    foo: -> (obj){ obj.do_foo },
    bar: -> (obj){ obj.do_bar }
  }  

  def call
    @commands.each { |command| SAFE_COMMANDS[command].call(self) }
  end

  private

  def do_foo 
    puts 'foo'
  end

  def do_bar
    puts 'bar'
  end

end
```

However you'll get the following error:

```
private method `do_foo' called for #<Thing:0x00007fdc018399f8 @commands=[:foo, :bar]> (NoMethodError)
```

This is because those methods are private and therefore inaccessible by the lambdas.

So here's what I'd recommend instead. Use `#send` but filter the commands first and raise an exception (or something similar) if an illegal command is issued.

```
class Thing

  def initialize
    @commands = [:do_foo, :do_bar, :do_bad_stuff, :do_really_bad_stuff]
  end
 
  SAFE_COMMANDS = %i{
    do_foo
    do_bar
  }

  def call
    illegal_commands = @commands - SAFE_COMMANDS
    raise("illegal commands: #{illegal_commands.join(', ')}") unless illegal_commands.empty?

    @commands.each { |command| self.send(command) }
  end

  private

  def do_foo 
    puts 'foo'
  end

  def do_bar
    puts 'bar'
  end

end
```

This creates and array of any commands not in your `SAFE_COMMANDS` array. If that array is empty then we've only been passed legal commands and we proceed. Otherwise we raise an exception, and nicely format those illegal commands to tell the user they 'done screwed up.'

```
illegal commands: do_bad_stuff, do_really_bad_stuff (RuntimeError)
```

But I'd actually recommend checking this at initialization time. I assume you are going to eventually pass these commands to the instance somehow so I made that change.

```
class Thing

  def initialize( *commands )
    commands = commands.map(&:to_sym)

    illegal_commands = commands - SAFE_COMMANDS
    raise("illegal commands: #{illegal_commands.join(', ')}") unless illegal_commands.empty?

    @commands = commands
  end
 
  SAFE_COMMANDS = %i{
    do_foo
    do_bar
  }

  def call
    @commands.each { |command| self.send(command) }
  end

  private

  def do_foo 
    puts 'foo'
  end

  def do_bar
    puts 'bar'
  end

end

# the exception is raised here
thing = Thing.new(:do_foo, :do_bar, :do_bad_stuff, :do_really_bad_stuff)

# rather than here
thing.call
```

I think filtering the command list rather than shenanigans with lambdas is *way* safer security wise, and way less complicated.